# RxJS: An Observable that takes its own old value as input

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

I'm trying to implement something like this:

```
// This obviously doesn't work, because we try to refer to `a` before it exists.
// c and m are some Observables.
const aSampled = a.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.sample(c),
  rxjs.operators.startWith(aInitial)
);
const a = m.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.withLatestFrom(aSampled),
  map(([mValue, oldAValue]) => {
    // Do something.
  }),
  rxjs.operators.startWith(aInitial)
);
```

Now that's obivously uncompilable nonsense, since we try to `sample` `a` before creating it, but hopefully it makes my intent clear: Every emitted value from `a` should depend on one of the old values previously emitted by `a`. Which old value of `a`, that's decided by when was the last time that `c` emitted something. It's kinda like calling `pairwise` on `a`, except that I don't want the last two values, but the latest and another from further back.

Note that if not for the `startWith(aInitial)` bits, this wouldn't even be a well-defined question, since the first value emitted by `a` would be defined cyclically, refering to itself. However, as long as the first value `a` is specified separately, the construction makes mathematical sense. I just don't know how to implement it in code in a clean way. My hunch is that there would be a long-winded way of doing this by writing a custom Subject of some kind, but something more elegant would be very welcome.

To make this a bit more concrete, in my use case I'm dealing with a click-and-drag-to-pan type of UI element. `m` is an Observable of `mousemove` events, `c` is an Observable of `mousedown` events. `a` would then be something that keeps changing based where the cursor is, and what the value of `a` was when the click-down happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, the basic streams of events are `mousemove` and a `mousedown`.

Based on these streams of events, you have to calculate a new stream `a`, which emits with the same frequency of `mousemove` but whose data are the result of some calculation based on the current position of the mouse and the value `a` had when the last `mousedown` emitted.

So, if this is true, we can simulate `mousemove` and `mousedown` with the following Observables

```
// the mouse is clicked every 1 second
const c = interval(1000).pipe(
    tap(cVal => console.log('click', cVal))
);
// the mouse moves diagonally and emits every 200 ms
const m = interval(200).pipe(
    map(mVal => [mVal, mVal]),
);
```

What we need is to have somehow at hand the value of the Observable `a` when `mousedown` emits. How can we get this?

Let's assume we have a `BehaviourSubject` called `value_of_a` whose initial value is `1` and that holds the value of `a`. If we had such Observable, we could get the its value when `mousedown` emits simply like this

```
const last_relevant_a = c.pipe(       // when mousedown emits
    switchMap(() => value_of_a.pipe(  // the control is switched to the Observable value_of_a
        take(1),                      // and we consider only its first value
    )),
);
```

With `m`, the mousemove Observable, and `last_relevant_a` we have all the Observable that we need. In fact we have just to combine their latest emissions to have all the elements we need to calculate the new value of `a`.

```
const a = combineLatest(m, last_relevant_a)
.submit(
   ([mouseVal, old_a_val] => {
      // do something to calculate the new value of a
   }
);
```

Now the only thing left to do is to make sure that `value_of_a` emits any value emitted by `a`. This can be accomplished calling `next` on `value_of_a` within the subscription of `a` itself.

Stitching it all together, the solution could be something like

```
const c = interval(1000).pipe(
    tap(cVal => console.log('click', cVal))
);

const m = interval(200).pipe(
    map(mVal => [mVal, mVal]),
);

const value_of_a = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);

const last_relevant_a = c.pipe(
    switchMap(cVal => value_of_a.pipe(
        take(1),
    )),
);

const a = combineLatest(m, last_relevant_a);

a.pipe(
    take(20)
)
.subscribe(
    val => {
        // new value of a calculated with an arbitrary logic
        const new_value_of_a = val[0][0] * val[0][1] * val[1];
        // the new value of a is emitted by value_of_a
        value_of_a.next(new_value_of_a);
    }
)
```

Probably this is also a use case for the `expand` operator, but it should be investigated.

Comment: This is pretty similar to the solution I posted myself, but better explained. Approved!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new subject called a previous subject based off a behavior subject.

The source to a behavior subject is here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts.

So lets create a previous subject that emits the current value along with the previous value.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { SubscriptionLike } from 'rxjs';
import { ObjectUnsubscribedError } from 'rxjs';

export class PreviousSubject<T> extends Subject<T[]> {

  _value: T[];

  constructor(value: T, previous?: T) {
    super();
    this._value = [value, previous];
  }

  get value(): T[] {
    return this.getValue();
  }

  /** @deprecated This is an internal implementation detail, do not use. */
  _subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T[]>): Subscription {
    const subscription = super._subscribe(subscriber);
    if (subscription && !(<SubscriptionLike>subscription).closed) {
      subscriber.next(this._value);
    }
    return subscription;
  }

  getValue(): T[] {
    if (this.hasError) {
      throw this.thrownError;
    } else if (this.closed) {
      throw new ObjectUnsubscribedError();
    } else {
      return this._value;
    }
  }

  next(value: T): void {
    this._value = [value, this._value[0]];
    super.next(this._value);
  }
}
```

See a demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wiayqx

Or vanilla JS if you don't want TypeScript

```js
const { Subject } = rxjs;

class PreviousSubject extends Subject {

  _value;

  constructor(value, previous) {
    super();
    this._value = [value, previous];
  }

  get value() {
    return this.getValue();
  }

  _subscribe(subscriber) {
    const subscription = super._subscribe(subscriber);
    if (subscription && !(subscription).closed) {
      subscriber.next(this._value);
    }
    return subscription;
  }

  getValue() {
    if (this.hasError) {
      throw this.thrownError;
    } else if (this.closed) {
      throw new ObjectUnsubscribedError();
    } else {
      return this._value;
    }
  }

  next(value) {
    this._value = [value, this._value[0]];
    super.next(this._value);
  }
}

let ps$ = new PreviousSubject('Start value');

ps$.subscribe(([current, previous]) => {
  console.log(`Current: ${current}, Previous: ${previous}`);
});

ps$.next('Value');
ps$.next('Another value');
ps$.next('Another value again');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of thought, here's my own solution, together with a minimal working example:

```
// Setup for MWE.
// Note that c just emits once a second, the actual values of it don't matter.
const c = rxjs.interval(1000).pipe(rxjs.operators.take(2));
const m = rxjs.interval(300).pipe(rxjs.operators.take(9));
const aInitial = -1;

// Initialize a.
const a = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject();
a.next(aInitial);

// For testing, log the values a emits.
a.subscribe((val) => {
  console.log(`a: ${val}`);
});

// Sample a at each emission of c.
const aSampled = a.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.sample(c),
  rxjs.operators.startWith(aInitial),
);

// Every time m emits, get also the latest sampled value of a, and do something
// with the two.
m.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.withLatestFrom(aSampled),
  rxjs.operators.map(([mValue, oldAValue]) => {
    // In place of actually computing something useful, just log the arguments
    // and for the sake of demonstration return their product.
    console.log(`m: ${mValue}, old a at last c-emission: ${oldAValue}`);
    return mValue*oldAValue;
  }),
).subscribe(a);  // Route the output back into a.
```

That outputs

```
a: -1
m: 0, old a at last c-emission: -1
a: 0
m: 1, old a at last c-emission: -1
a: -1
m: 2, old a at last c-emission: -1
a: -2
m: 3, old a at last c-emission: -2
a: -6
m: 4, old a at last c-emission: -2
a: -8
m: 5, old a at last c-emission: -2
a: -10
m: 6, old a at last c-emission: -10
a: -60
m: 7, old a at last c-emission: -10
a: -70
m: 8, old a at last c-emission: -10
a: -80
```

The trick is that setting `a` up as a Subject allows us to first emit its initial value, and then after hook it up to the pipe that has as one of its inputs the older, sampled values of `a`. Plain Observables don't allow this (AFAIK) because you have to define all their inputs at creation time. No need for a cusom Subject class though.